# On eclipse, developing for Android, where can i see the output of System.out.println()?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm using the Android Developer Tools on eclipse, plus Java (obviously). I'm quite new to Java, and i don't know where the output can be seen. I tried the obvious: the console, but the string wasn't there. I tried the Logcat, but the string wasn't there either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't System.out.println work? (in Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use `System.out.println()` on Android. You use `Log.v()`, `Log.d()`, etc.

[Documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

Comment: However, System.out.println() is displayed in the Logcat as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is displayed in the Logcat. You can choose to display Logcat if you go to Windows - Show Views -> Android -> Logcat.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a visual response on the phone, use Toast.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Log.e(),Log.v(),Log.d() for displaying output or exception and you can see that in **logcat**.

Answer (score 1):

@EboMike is right, anyway, you can see the output in the LogCat view

```
 Window --> Show View --> LogCat
```

Assumes, that you have Android's ADT plugin installed.