# Does Sytem.out.println work in Android?

Tags: android, printing, android-logcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't System.out.println work? (in Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android)

I want to print something into console. What can I do? because System.out.println doesnt work. Some people says it works bur some of them says dosnt work. Which one right?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println()` works, also `Log.d("TAG", "message");` works, but you need to open the LogCat view in eclipse and *not* the console view.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Log class from the android SDK. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

like

```
final string tag = "myApp";
Log.d(tag,"hello world");
```