# Does the Android API support console UI?

Tags: android, console

I wonder know if is there any kind of **support for console UI on Android platform**.
I mean something like *printf* / *scanf* C functions or the *System.Out* / *System.in* Java classes with relative console creation.

**e.g.** Symbyan Platforms have *CConsole* class, Windows has console subsystem and API, so has Linux, and so on.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't System.out.println work? (in Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

You can view your log by typing 'adb logcat' in the terminal (android-sdk-dir/platform-tools needs to be in your PATH).

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder know if is there any kind of support for console UI on Android platform.

Not for real apps.