# Android. System.out.println() doesn't work. What is the proper method to write?

Tags: android, stream

I used to write something like `System.out.println(...);` for tracing the information in Java.

But it doesn't write any messages to my IDE console, when I use it for programming for Android. What is the proper way to write to standard output stream?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android

Answer (score 3):

I've always used the log functions though there might be a better way.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: yeah, the system out is either through the screen or through your logcat. Read up on the DDMS

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println()` messages will come in the **Logcat** window in Eclipse, it wont come in Console window.
For Android it is better to use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) functions.

Answer (score 0):

See also http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html on how to gather logs.

Answer (score 0):

You must the android.util.Log class. This class ptint the logs in the LogCat view of Eclipse.

Log.v("SOMETAG", "Message for the log");

Answer (score 0):

with the LOG function. see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html