# SearchView's OnCloseListener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-actionbar

I'm trying to add support for the `SearchView` in the Android 3.0+ ActionBar, but I can't get the `OnCloseListener` to work.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_textbox).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            searchLibrary(newText);
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { return false; }
    });
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            System.out.println("Testing. 1, 2, 3...");
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

The search works great and every is working except for the `OnCloseListener`. Nothing is being printed to Logcat. Here's the Logcat for when I'm pressing the "Close" button:

```
02-17 13:01:52.914: I/TextType(446): TextType = 0x0
02-17 13:01:57.344: I/TextType(446): TextType = 0x0
02-17 13:02:02.944: I/TextType(446): TextType = 0x0
```

I've looked through [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnCloseListener.html) and samples, but nothing seemed to change it. I'm running it on a Asus Transformer Prime and a Galaxy Nexus, both on Ice Cream Sandwich. Any ideas?

**Update:**

Yes - `System.out.println()` *does* work. Here's proof:

```
   @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    System.out.println(newText + "hello");
    searchLibrary(newText);
    return false;
 }
```

Results in this Logcat:

```
02-17 13:04:20.094: I/System.out(21152): hello
02-17 13:04:24.914: I/System.out(21152): thello
02-17 13:04:25.394: I/System.out(21152): tehello
02-17 13:04:25.784: I/System.out(21152): teshello
02-17 13:04:26.064: I/System.out(21152): testhello
```

Comment: Hmm, Works OK for me with Android 3.2 but NOT for 4.0+

Comment: Raised bug, [25758](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25758)

Comment: I'm glad it is not just me having this problem. Anyone have any other hacks other than the one below?

Comment: I have learnt two things if `showAsAction` is set to `always`. Search box has a **close** button of its own but if it is set to `ifRoom | collapseActionView` it expands on the action bar.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I also meet this problem, and I have no choice but give up "oncloselistener". Instead, you can get your menuItem, then `setOnActionExpandListener`. Then override unimplents methods.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("*******","onMenuItemActionExpand");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
    //do what you want to when close the sesarchview
    //remember to return true;
    Log.d("*******","onMenuItemActionCollapse");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I believe we're only talking about ActionBar's SearchView which is only honeycomb+

Comment: don't bother using onCloseListener, just use this one with your menu item.

Comment: I think you can use MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener for earlier API levels:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener.html

Comment: Full answer: `if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.NMr1)
                item.SetOnActionExpandListener(this);
            else
                MenuItemCompat.SetOnActionExpandListener(item, this);`

Answer (score 62):

For Android API 14+ (ICS and greater) use this code:

```
// When using the support library, the setOnActionExpandListener() method is
// static and accepts the MenuItem object as an argument
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menuItem, new OnActionExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        // Do something when collapsed
        return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        // Do something when expanded
        return true;  // Return true to expand action view
    }
});
```

For more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Ref: [onActionCollapse/onActionExpand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener.html#onMenuItemActionCollapse%28android.view.MenuItem%29)

Answer (score 31):

For this problem I came up with something like this,

```
private SearchView mSearchView;

@TargetApi(14)
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.conversation_index_activity_menu, menu);

    mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.itemSearch).getActionView();

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.itemSearch);

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    {
        menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item)
            {
                // Do something when collapsed
                Log.i(TAG, "onMenuItemActionCollapse " + item.getItemId());
                return true; // Return true to collapse action view
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i(TAG, "onMenuItemActionExpand " + item.getItemId());
                return true;
            }
        });
    } else
    {
        // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
        mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onClose()
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "mSearchView on close ");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Comment: What happens if you have always expanded using setIconofiedByDefault(false) ? It dosen't works... :(

Answer (score 20):

I ran into same problem on android 4.1.1. Looks like it is a known bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25758

Anyway, as a workaround i used state change listener (when SearchView is detached from action bar, it is also closed obviously).

```
view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new OnAttachStateChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View arg0) {
        // search was detached/closed
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View arg0) {
        // search was opened
    }
});
```

Above code worked well in my case.

---

I post same answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24573266/2162924

Comment: Yes, that bug was created right after I posted this question. See the comments on the original question.

Comment: Oh ok, see now. But anyway, maybe this workaround with state change listener might be useful for others also.

Comment: While disappointing that OnCloseListener doesn't work as you'd think, this is actually a nice, clean solution. Kudos!

Answer (score 12):

I ended up using a bit of a hack, that works well for my purpose - not sure it'll work with all purposes. Anyway, I'm doing a check to see if the search query is empty. This is not really related to the `SearchView`'s `OnCloseListener` though - that still doesn't work!

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText.length() > 0) {
                    // Search
                } else {
                    // Do something when there's no input
                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { return false; }
        });
```

Answer (score 11):

Well, this solved my problem:

Menu item with `showAsAction="always"`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

and in activity

```
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {

            Log.i("SearchView:", "onClose");
            searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Setting `always` value to `showAsAction` attribute solves the problem. 
The important thing is that when `always` value `is not` present in `showAsAction`, expanded `SearchView` presents close button(cross icon) only if query in `SearchView` is non-null String. The `SearchView.onCloseClicked` that handles close button events tells that callback to `OnCloseListener` is called only if query is empty, if it's not - it's cleared first - but then, after clearing query close button disappears and we are unable to deliver `onClose` callback to `OnCloseListener`

Comment: Just a hint: this method is called when the user closes the search view (quite obvious, but it took me a few times to realize). The fist time the user click on the X it erases text, and I didnt get that update, on the second click on the X it closes the SearchView and the onClose is invoked. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

In order to make the `OnCloseListener` work, make sure that `showAsAction` is set to `always` in the search menu item.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".SearchActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_toolbar"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create the menu item with the `app:showAsAction` set to always.

```
<item   
 android:id="@+id/action_search"  
 android:title="..."  
 android:icon="..."  
 app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"  
 app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

When creating the `SearchView` in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method do something similar

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
final SearchView search = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
search.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_brand_item));
search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    // add your code
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // add your code 
    return false;
  }
});
search.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onClose() {
    // add your code here
    return false;
  }
});
search.setIconifiedByDefault(true); // make sure to set this to true
```

The `search.setIconifiedByDefault(true)` needs to be set to `true` to call the `onClose()` method on the `SearchView.OnCloseListener()` created above.

Comment: Just for anyone who wants to understand what setIconifiedByDefault() does,

It Sets the default or resting state of the search field. If true, a single search icon is shown by default and expands to show the text field and other buttons when pressed. Also, if the default state is iconified, then it collapses to that state when the close button is pressed.

Answer (score 3):

```
    searchView.setOnCloseListener {
        d("click", "close clicked")
        return@setOnCloseListener false
    }
```

if you click on close searchView ->

D/click: close clicked

Comment: Answers with a blob of code and some cryptic words isn't particularly clear. Just use natural language to describe why you think this solves the problem, and then show the implementation of the solution.

Comment: I did not understand this cryptic "explanation" either, but it still led me to the correct solution in my case. My search view wasn't closing and my `setOnCloseListener ` is very simple. I compared mine with the one from this answer and noticed, that I return `true`. Since I changed it to `false` it works fine, now. It's easy to miss such little things, so it helps to compare your own code to foreign examples.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem with onCloseListener not invoking for the SearchView.
Understand from the bug issue raised in [25758](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25758), and some postings I have read, to invoke onCloseListener, you need to set:

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
```

But for my case I wanted to have the search view opened & not iconified all the time. I manage to resolve this by adding one more line below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_bar, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    return true;
}
```

The searchView.setIconified(false) will cause the searchView to open up, despite setting the default to iconified to true in the previous line. In this way, I managed to have both a SearchView 
that opens up all the time & having it invoke the onCloseListener.

Answer (score 1):

For `MenuItemCompat` problem I added ViewTreeObserver to track the visibility state. You can check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762632/1633609

Answer (score 1):

I used the SearchView close button and set a setOnClickListener on it

```
searchView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.search_close_btn).setOnClickListener {
    searchView.setQuery("", false)
    searchView.clearFocus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `OnCloseListener` is not called is because there is a bug in the Android code -- the listener is only called if you also call `setIconifiedByDefault(true)`.

Comment: I just tried adding setIconifiedByDefault(true) but it is not called

Comment: @Joseph Earl: I'm having a similar problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702055/android-how-do-i-get-searchview-close-button-to-return-to-search-edittext?noredirect=1#comment74449117_43702055.  Any thoughts or ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

seems an old thread already, but I thought I got the same problem API 18 in the first beginning.  After googled around, found this thread, another hour read the javadoc tried and errored for something I don't pretend fully understand in javadoc, the following work for me now:

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

   // OnQueryTextListener
   @Override
   public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
      Log.d(tag, "onQueryTextSubmit: " + query);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
      Log.d(tag, "onQueryTextChange: " + query);
      return true;
   }

   // OnCloseListener
   @Override
   public boolean onClose() {
      Log.w(tag, "onClose: ");
      return false;
   }
```

I played with true/false a bit, that somehow makes the difference, and it works for me now.  Hopefully, it could save someone time.

Answer (score 0):

It's a workaround but has worked for me

```
  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                String lastText;

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
                    if (lastText != null && lastText.length() > 1 && newText.isEmpty()) {
                        // close ctn clicked

                        return true;
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while trying to detect the showing/dismissal of the SearchView. I ended up using a different listener and it worked for what I need:

```
        setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                // SearchView is being shown
            } else {
                // SearchView was dismissed
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
searchView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
    System.out.println("This is Fired When Search view was Expanded");
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
    System.out.println("This is Fired When Search view was Closed");
  }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

There is no console in Android to log to.  Instead, use the android logging framework:

```
Log.d("Test Tag", "Testing.  1, 2, 3...");
```

See also this question: [Why doesn't "System.out.println" work in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android)

Comment: Not true, it works just fine. Please see my updated question - I've added a line in the onQueryTextChange method to prove it. Also tried adding Log.d(), but that didn't display anything either.

Comment: Oh, my bad!  Looks like somewhere along the way they've decided to output System.out.println to the Log.i.  Good luck

Answer (score -3):

There are two common patterns for `SearchView.setOnCloseListener()`.  This is really true of all listeners, but I'm addressing your question specifically.  The first way is to create a listener function and attach it to a member variable, and the second is to make the class implement the interface and have the handler be a member function.

Creating a listener object looks like this:

```
private SearchView mSearchView;
private final SearchView.OnCloseListener mOnCloseListener = 
    new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        public boolean onClose() {
            doStuff();
            return myBooleanResult;
        }
    };
mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(mOnCloseListener);
```

Implementing listener at class level looks like this:

```
public class MyClass implements OnCloseListener {
    private SearchView mSearchView;

    public MyClass(...) {
        mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        doStuff();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have not seen any examples that create the `OnCloseListener` ad-hoc, as you did in your question.

Comment: Hey Sparky, thanks for commenting on this. I don't really see how that should change anything. A nested listener is a valid way of making it as well, and it works on Honeycomb as you can see based on the comments here. I haven't had any issues with nested listeners on ICS other than this - which again works on Honeycomb.

Comment: By nested listeners I mean anonymous inner classes.

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't matter.  I'm only commenting on what's present in the code base.  I'll look and see if maybe the conditions in which onClose were redefined.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand Java -- it's called an anonymous inner class.