# android-seach option in actionBar without creating custom theme

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to put a search option on the right of the action bar without having to create a custom action bar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this code If you are action bar sherlock, you can implement search menu in action bar

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add("Search")
         .setIcon(R.drawable.search)
         .setActionView(R.layout.search_layout)
         .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_COLLAPSE_VIEW);

       return true;
    }


    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
         //What do i write here?
         return true;
    }
```

### In search_layout.xml

place a edittext that's enough.

[Normal Android Actionbar search widget Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556795/android-actionbar-search-widget-implementation)