# Expand Search View to use entire Action Bar (hide other things)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have a `SearchView` inside my `ActionBar`, and I want to use the entire `ActionBar` when the search icon is pressed, but I can only use the `ActionBar` free space

eg.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rOUo.jpg

my menu code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="br.com.moderna.houaiss.activity.SearchActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    android:title="@string/search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/backWardHistory"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_48dp"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/back_history"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/forWardHistory"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_white_48dp"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/forward_history"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_home"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_about"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_configuration"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_configuration"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_logout"/>
```

I had tryed `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`, but I need them to be always on my `ActionBar`, and not inside my menu.

EDIT ------

Thanks to @Simas,

I used setOnActionExpandListener method to achieve this effect

```
final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(final MenuItem item) {
            SearchActivity.this.setItemsVisibility(menu, searchItem, false);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(final MenuItem item) {
            SearchActivity.this.setItemsVisibility(menu, searchItem, true);
            return true;
        }
    });


private void setItemsVisibility(final Menu menu, final MenuItem exception,
        final boolean visible) {
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); ++i) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item != exception)
            item.setVisible(visible);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Well you could imitate that yourself by hiding all the other items when the `SearchView` is expanded:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (android.widget.SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    // Detect SearchView icon clicks
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setItemsVisibility(menu, searchItem, false);
        }
    });
    // Detect SearchView close
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            setItemsVisibility(menu, searchItem, true);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void setItemsVisibility(Menu menu, MenuItem exception, boolean visible) {
    for (int i=0; i<menu.size(); ++i) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item != exception) item.setVisible(visible);
    }
}
```

Comment: this helped me to achieve a solution

Comment: searchView.setOnCloseListener not work so use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener()....

Comment: Very well defined .Thanks

Comment: @Simas You saved my Day nd Time...Thanks for Amazing answer...+1 vote for your ans.

Comment: for me `setOnCloseListener` wasn't being called. solution >> 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920960/searchview-oncloselistener-does-not-get-invoked

Answer (score 14):

This would be a late answer but you could add this attribute to your menu item and the work is done for you.

```
app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
```

Keyword here being the collapseActionView.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me, only works for the search item that has the actionview

Comment: This is the simplest and most direct solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I tried this line of code to make the searchview expand the full width available. This works when there are other items shown in the actionbar either.

```
searchView.setMaxWidth(android.R.attr.width);
```

Comment: putting there `android.R.attr.width` is confusing, as it has anything to do with width or any value under that attribute, it just happens that resource id is a big integer number.

it make more sense to wtire:
`searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Answer (score 0):

"collapseActionView" attribute works for menu item in menu.xml to hide other things and add back action button-

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

In few case if it doesn't work, we can explicitly hide/show other menu items by using MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener as below-

```
        action_search.setOnActionExpandListener(new  MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            action_setting.setVisible(false); // to hide item
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            action_setting.setVisible(true); // to show item
            return true;
        }
    });
```