# Hiding all icons when user touches to search

Tags: android

I want to hide all icons in action bar when user touches the search icon. But one icon is not hiding.

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">






      <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_36dp"
          android:title="Ara"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
          app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>


    <item android:id="@+id/action_shuffle"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_autorenew_white_24dp"
          android:title="Karıştır"
          app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_premium"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_white_24dp"
        android:title="Premium"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_people_white_24dp"
          android:title="Takip Listesi"
          app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
          android:title="Settings"
          app:showAsAction="always" />

        <item android:id="@+id/action_fullpicture"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_picture"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          android:visible="false" />    
</menu>
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

How can I hide `action_shuffle` too? Other icons automaticly hiding I didn't do anything special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the `app:showAsAction = "always"` to `app:showAsAction = "ifRoom"`.

Other way could be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577820/4385913), take a look.

Comment: @TolgayToklar all of them

Comment: I tried it but I don't like it becase it is hiding important icons.

Comment: Then try the other way I tested it and it worked, and if you put "always" I don't know how it will look if you put the app on a small device... it's recomendable to use "ifRoom" AFAIK.