# Toolbar-SearchView strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

When search-view is expanded and click on overflow menu icon it randomly adds menu items, and when exit from search-view (collapse search) the query-hint of search-view is shown behind the toolbar-title.

I am using

```
android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
android-support-v7-appcompat_23.1
```

[image]
update added screenshot

Comment: no,  hint is not shown

Comment: your screenshots are amazing

Comment: i'm using the same thing but no problem like you, therefore show some more code if possible

Comment: i have solved the issue by invisible other menu item link http://stackoverflow.com/a/30577820/2685454