# Remove extra menu when search view is click

Tags: android, kotlin, menuitem, searchview, android-menu

In my project, I try to remove the extra menu when the search view is clicked and return the menus when canceling the search view. Please find the screenshot below

[image]
[image]
[image]

I use this below code to hide and show the menu, but it is not working as expected. Please find the screenshot below of my implementation.

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
  if (searchMenu is MenuItem) {
            searchMenu.setOnActionExpandListener(object :
                MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {
                override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(p0: MenuItem): Boolean {
                   activity?.invalidateOptionsMenu()
                     return true
                }

                override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(p0: MenuItem): Boolean {
                    toolbar?.menu?.findItem(R.id.menu_add_recipients)?.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER)
                    return true
                }

            })
        }
```

Also, I have tried using `setOnSearchClickListener` and `setOnCloseListener` for hiding and showing the menu, but that also not working. Could anyone please help me with this

Comment: You sample code lacks a lot of context. When do you call that block? How are you setting up your menus to begin with?

Comment: Someone had the same problem. Here you can check the solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577252/expand-search-view-to-use-entire-action-bar-hide-other-things

Comment: The only way is to hide other menu items when the search is activated. For example https://github.com/sdex/ActivityManager/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sdex/activityrunner/util/UIUtils.java#L40

Answer (score 0):

```
//hide
toolbar?.menu?.findItem(R.id.menu_add_recipients)?.isVisible = false

//show
toolbar?.menu?.findItem(R.id.menu_add_recipients)?.isVisible = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the misunderstanding. Please share your Xml file or compose code as it seems to have some extra padding or margins added to your view