# Set search widget back button functionality

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have implemented the Android `search widget` in my `navigation drawer` based app. I have set it to open the keyboard and focus the `editText` when clicking on the search icon. I want to set the back button (up button) to hide the keyboard. I have searched the web for the `R.id` of the up button, and found this `android.R.id.home`. So I have set it to be:

```java
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
    case android.R.id.home:
        hideKeyboard();
        break;
    ...
}
```

I debugged the code and noticed that clicking on the `navigation bar` icon fires up the `android.R.id.home`, but hitting the up button of the search widget doesn't even enter the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` function.
I have also tried this:

```java
searchView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            hideKeyboard();
        }
    }
});
```

But didn't work.

How can I hide the keyboard when pressing the back (up) button?

Setting the search view:

```java
private void setSearchView(Menu menu) {
    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Home.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code *should* work:

```
searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {
    @Override
    public bool OnClose() {
        searchView.clearFocus();
        return true;
});
```

However this didn't work for me for some reason. :-/

I found the workaround below [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920960/searchview-oncloselistener-does-not-get-invoked/24573266#24573266):

```
searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

searchView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new OnAttachStateChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
        searchView.clearFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
        
    }
});
```

---

I don't think that using `android.R.id.home` will work since I think that `onOptionsItemSelected(android.R.id.home)` will only be called once the SearchView has been closed.

Comment: Have you check this thread? [SearchView's OnCloseListener doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327826/searchviews-oncloselistener-doesnt-work/12975254#12975254) . Second part, that author shouldn't rely on `android.R.id.home` is fully corrent, though.