# How to hide menu item from toolbar when click on search icon in android

Tags: android

[image]My toolbar contains search icon and refresh icon,when i click on search icon then search view inflate from onCreateOptionMenu() but the refresh icon does not get hide.If i hide refresh icon in onMenuItemActionExpand() then on back press of search view back icon both menu items search and refresh gets hide and default setting icon gets visible.Below is the code which i have implemented.Please help me!!!

MenuItem.java

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
              getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
              item_search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
              item_refresh = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);

           final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item_search);
            searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // hide action item
                    if (menu != null) {
                        menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(false);
                    }

                }
            });
            searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onClose() {
                    // re-show the action button
                    if (menu != null) {
                        menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(true);
                    }
                    return false;

                }
            });
```

Comment: It seems that it's a bug from android, you can use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24573266/3882352 "another solution")!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SearchView.OnCloseListener does not get invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920960/searchview-oncloselistener-does-not-get-invoked)

Answer (score 0):

```
​MenuItem action_search;
MenuItem action_refresh;
 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     action_search = menu.findItem(R.id. action_search);
     action_refresh = menu.findItem(R.id. action_refresh);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          item_search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
          item_refresh = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);

       final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item_search);
        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // hide action item
                if (action_refresh != null) {
                    action_refresh.setVisible(false);
                  invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

            }
        });
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                // re-show the action button
                if (action_search != null) {
                    action_search.setVisible(true);
                }
               if (action_refresh != null) {
                   action_refresh.setVisible(true);
                }
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return false;

            }
        });

​
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply!!! Where should i call this,means after setVisibility false or true

Comment: After setting the visibility

Comment: I have tried in setOnSearchClickListener() it doesnot allow on clicking search icon and in setOnCloseListener() nothing changed.Please elaborate your answer

Comment: if (menu != null) {
                    menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(true);

                }
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: With this code,refresh icon appears when click on search icon

Comment: just change the visibility of refrsh icon too

Comment: Where should i change the visibility of refresh icon

Comment: See the image i have posted

Comment: Hide the refresh icon where you hide the search icon and show the where you show the refresh icon. you can upvote my post if it helps you anyway.

Comment: Have you seen the image,this appears when i click on search icon,the refresh icon appearing.But i don't want to show refresh icon.

Comment: I have read your comment.The search icon is hiding due to search view.I have not written any code to hide search view

Comment: Can u tell me.why u are using item1,action_search,item_search 3 variable name for one value.

Comment: Sorry its my mistake. I mean it for the 2 menu items.

Comment: What i actually think is,you are not getting my point.What i want

Comment: See my question,and image as i don't want refresh icon when user click on search icon.But with your code i have posted the image the refresh icon is appearing.

Comment: Could you update the question with your current code

Comment: I have find the solution,by using always instead of ifroom in menu.xml. It start working fine.Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Well you could imitate that yourself by hiding all the other items when the SearchView is expanded:

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (android.widget.SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    // Detect SearchView icon clicks
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setItemsVisibility(menu, searchItem, false);
        }
    });
    // Detect SearchView close
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            setItemsVisibility(menu, searchItem, true);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void setItemsVisibility(Menu menu, MenuItem exception, boolean visible) {
    for (int i=0; i<menu.size(); ++i) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item != exception) item.setVisible(visible);
    }
}
```