# How can we intercept the left top arrow image which opens on click of searchview

Tags: java, android

In my app on click of the searchview icon,search view is opened along with launcher icon with < arrow beside launch icon following image,search functionality works fine,but how can we intercept < arrow icon or how can we call this icon as i have to perform sone functionlity on clik of the image?Any ideas??please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do is:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:

            //your code here

        return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the reply,but this is getting called on second time click,on first click i dont know whats happening nothing is getting called.

Comment: And you are calling it from your activity or fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late. But I found a workout to your problem in this response (I was having the same problem):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12975254/2789106

P.S: Note this does not intercept the click in the < arrow, but intercepts the callback called when the searchView collapses. But, as you are using searchView, this will work (worked for me =D).