# android searchview setOnActionExpandListener on Honeycomb 3.2

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb, searchview

I'm developing an app for Android 3.2 and greater with `android-support-v4`. I need to implement `OnActionExpandListener` for "intercept" when SearchView in the actionbar is expanded and when is collapsed. My code for Android 4.0 and higher it's ok, but for 3.2 no.

> menu.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

> MyActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reader, menu);

    final MenuItem searchMI = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    if(searchView == null) {
        //searchView = (SearchView) searchMI.getActionView();
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMI);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                //some code
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(searchMI, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMI, new OnActionExpandListener() {

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener#onMenuItemActionExpand(android.view.MenuItem)
             */
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMenuItemActionExpand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener#onMenuItemActionCollapse(android.view.MenuItem)
             */
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMenuItemActionExpand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    } else {
        searchMI.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MenuItem#onMenuItemActionExpand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MenuItem#onMenuItemActionExpand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Why, for Honeycomb, methods of listener is not invoked?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Just a passing note, since good answers are posted below. There are two problems: (1) should be "app:showAsAction", not "android:showAsaction", and also "app:actionViewClass". (2) The code itself should unconditionally use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener regardless of platform. Ironically everyone who arrives here has problem #1; but OP's code doesn't have problem #1; it has problem #2. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You probably missed the fact (like I did) that `MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener' interface has a static implementation, and is not an instance method.

So, if you have a class that implements `MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener` then in that class you need to install it as the listener like this:

```java
MenuItem menuItem =  menu.findItem(R.id.search);
if (menuItem != null) {
  MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menuItem,this);
  MenuItemCompat.setActionView(menuItem, mSearchView);
}
```

The same paradigm applies to setActionView ... rather than invoke `menuItem.setActionView(this)`, you pass the menuItem as the first argument to the static version `MenuItemCompat.setActionView` and follow with the other argument(s).

Comment: You solution works, thanks alot 
One more thing the answer above you is also necessary for proper working 
"For MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener to work you should add "collapseActionView" added in the menu item"

Answer (score 24):

For MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener to work you should add "**collapseActionView**" added in the menu item - 
for example -

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

And in the onCreateOptionsMenu you can use it this way -

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menu_search,
            new OnActionExpandListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item)
                {
                    // Do something when collapsed
                    return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item)
                {
                    // Do something when expanded
                    return true; // Return true to expand action view
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that `MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(...)` is not working if you don't pass:

```
    searchItem
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
                    | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

But this is changing the SearchView and is replacing the DrawerToggle with back arrow.

I wanted to keep the original views and still track the Expanded/Collapsed state and use supported Search View.

**Solution:**

When `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` is changing the view state the LinearLayout view's, with id `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_edit_frame`, visibility value is being changed from `View.VISIBLE` to `View.GONE` and opposite. So I add ViewTreeObserver to track the visibility change of the search edit frame.

menu_search.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

In the activity:

```
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

..........

private View mSearchEditFrame;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
    mSearchEditFrame = searchView
            .findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_edit_frame);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = mSearchEditFrame.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        int oldVisibility = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            int currentVisibility = mSearchEditFrame.getVisibility();

            if (currentVisibility != oldVisibility) {
                if (currentVisibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "EXPANDED");
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "COLLAPSED");
                }

                oldVisibility = currentVisibility;
            }

        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Listener should be MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() .

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem,
            new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {

}
```

Comment: In my code: MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMI, new OnActionExpandListener() {...}) OnActionExpandListener is in MenuItemCompat class. Your suggestion not work.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, 
your solution is work for me. and i'd like to vote you up, but i just realized i have only 1 reputation，(；′⌒`)

actually, my solution is similar to your, there is just one different in the menu xml file like this:

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/apps_menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/apps_menu_search"
    android:visible="true"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```