# How to support searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener in API level 8+?

Tags: android, android-support-library, searchview, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I am using ActionBarActivity ,How to support searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener in API level 8+ ? It says that minimum API level 14 is required for this.

Below is the my code, Currently I’m suppressing the error and allowing the code execution only if the API is >=14 .

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_home_screen, menu);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
                .getActionView(searchItem);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    hideProgressBar();
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    showProgressBar();
                    selectItem(lastSelectedItemPosition);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: I answered the question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28762632/1633609

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#setOnActionExpandListener%28android.view.MenuItem,%20android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener%29), which is the backport of `OnActionExpandedListener`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `ViewTreeObserver` to track the visibility state of `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_edit_frame`. You can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762632/1633609

*This is the copy of my solution from the other question:*

I found that `MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(...)` is not working if you don't pass:

```
    searchItem
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
                    | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

But this is changing the SearchView and is replacing the DrawerToggle with back arrow.

I wanted to keep the original views and still track the Expanded/Collapsed state and use supported Search View.

**Solution:**

When `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` is changing the view state the LinearLayout view's, with id `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_edit_frame`, visibility value is being changed from `View.VISIBLE` to `View.GONE` and opposite. So I add ViewTreeObserver to track the visibility change of the search edit frame.

menu_search.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

In the activity:

```
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

..........

private View mSearchEditFrame;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
    mSearchEditFrame = searchView
            .findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_edit_frame);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = mSearchEditFrame.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        int oldVisibility = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            int currentVisibility = mSearchEditFrame.getVisibility();

            if (currentVisibility != oldVisibility) {
                if (currentVisibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "EXPANDED");
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "COLLAPSED");
                }

                oldVisibility = currentVisibility;
            }

        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, the MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener interface itself is available from API level 14 too. If your question related to searching: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: I just want to know when the searchview is expanded and when it is collapsed.

Comment: As i see in the docs, the whole expandation thing was introduced with API level 14

Comment: I was looking for what ianhanniballake  has answered. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it after I commented again and it's great I did not hear about this interface :)