# Disable button when ActionBar search view opened and enable it when closed

Tags: java, android

How can I do something like this ?

- When the ActionBar searchview is closed, the button is enabled.

[image]

- When the ActionBar searchview is opened, the button is disabled.

[image]

Are there listeners that I can use ? Or am I forced to use something like a while loop or something else ?

For the case when SearchView is opened, I know I can use `menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener`, but for the closing I don't know...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    //...

    menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            findViewById(R.id.button).setEnabled(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327826/searchviews-oncloselistener-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know when the `SearchView` is opening or closing you can use `OnActionExpandListener`:

- when is closing `onMenuItemActionCollapse` will be called.
- when is opening `onMenuItemActionExpand` will be called.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    //...

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            findViewById(R.id.button).setEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            findViewById(R.id.button).setEnabled(true);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```