# ActionBar search view, how to handle left arrow click?

Tags: android, event-handling, searchview

Here is the picture:
[image]

How can I handle left arrow click?
I did my search through intent, that is OK:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        mFilter = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        ...search query
    }
}
```

and my close button code:

```
ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
...
}
```

How can I handle left arrow click?

Comment: And what's wrong?

Comment: How can I handle left arrow click?

Comment: Why do you want it?

Comment: I handle this event in one activity, as I shower above, so when I press left arrow button , search view is closed,and nothing more. I want to clear filter on this click, show full list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// When using the support library, the setOnActionExpandListener() method is
// static and accepts the MenuItem object as an argument
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menuItem, new OnActionExpandListener() {
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
    // Do something when collapsed
    return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
    // Do something when expanded
    return true;  // Return true to expand action view
}
});
```

This is from here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186164/4200187

Answer (score 0):

There is [`OnCloseListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnCloseListener(android.widget.SearchView.OnCloseListener)) in SearchView widget.

```
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: nope, this doesn't work. I press arrow when debugging, nothing hapend.