# SearchView's onClose listener never runs

Tags: android, android-search

Got a `SearchView` (androidx, not support lib)

I have added its proper listeners like:

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
       Toaster.show(this, "onQueryTextSubmit!");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
       Toaster.show(this, "onQueryTextChange!");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
       Toaster.show(this, "onClose!");
       return true;
}
```

Both `onQueryTextSubmit` and `onQueryTextChange` works well. However, when I click on the small X on the right side of the `SearchView`, the search view does get cleared, but the `onClose` **listener never runs.**

In the official docs it says about setOnCloseListener the following:

> "Sets a listener to inform when the user closes the SearchView."

I think I use this properly, **yet it is not triggered.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Weird thing is in my project `searchview.setOnCloseListener` works.

Comment: make sure you have register `setOnCloseListener()` to your searchview like this `searchview.setOnCloseListener(this)`

Comment: I wish this link will help you more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327826/searchviews-oncloselistener-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up:

```
   View searchViewsCloseBtn = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
        searchViewsCloseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Toaster.show(myContext, "I hate this platform.");
            }
        });
```

`"R.id.search_close_btn"` is the actual reference to the **SearchView's close btn.**

If you manually set an onClickListener it works.