# SearchView onClose not called

Tags: android

I am using SearchView in the menu of my toolbar within a fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_songbook_filter, menu);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setIconified(true);
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    mSearchView.onActionViewExpanded();
    mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            // Never gets called
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This is my menu item:

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```

I can perfectly receive `setOnQueryTextListener` - no problem at all. But I cannot receive the OnClose. I have tried to switch from `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` to `android.widget.SearchView` but it does not work either. I have also tried `onActionViewCollapsed` and `onActionViewExpanded` which also do not work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580663/searchviews-onclose-listener-never-runs) solution does not work either. **Does anyone know how I can receive the OnClose?**

Comment: Try to replace app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" to app:showAsAction="always" in your layout

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920960/searchview-oncloselistener-does-not-get-invoked

Comment: @AlexeyBilousov: Does not work

Comment: @Fadman: Does not work.