# android, respond to layout resize

Tags: android, layout, admob

I'm using an AdMob view which has no width/height until it's ready to be displayed and then it expands. is there a way to get notified when that happens? I need to resize my layout when that happens.

Comment: possible duplicate, with a selected answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433140/android-get-admob-banner-height-when-appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the `onLayout` method of your view:

```
    View view = new View(this) {
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
            super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
            // Do some stuff
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
AdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
  public void onRecieveAd(){
      //resize your view
  }
});
```

If you want to know when your adview has recieve an ad, then you can use an `onFailedToRecieveAd` listener.

```
AdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
  public void onFailedToRecieveAd(){
      //do something else
  }
});
```

- [How to know if AdMob ad has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797007/how-to-know-if-admob-ad-has-been-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

If you use relative layouts that put the adMob in an effective location, then it works best. You can actually place the adMob image such that it is a part of the layout. When the image comes in, the layout gets shuffled around appropriately.

Alternatively, you can look into adListeners

```
public interface AdListener {
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad);
  public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, AdRequest.ErrorCode error);
  public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad);
}
```

Essentially, you can set the addListener and do something when an ad was received. But I recommend using a relative layout with the adMob included in the XML code, such that the layout automatically adjusts when the image appears/disappears.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
...
make admob...
...
 AdSize adSize = AdSize.createAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER, this);
 int h = adSize.getHeightInPixels(getBaseContext());
 myListView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, h);
}
```