# Android Interstitial ads add test device?

Tags: android, ads, interstitial

You can easily add test devices with banner ads so you don't get banned by accidentally clicking on them. However I cannot find how to add test devices to interstitial ads. I assume you also can be banned if you click accidentally on them.

Can you add test devices to these and if so, how? I can't find it on the official google guide, nor on SA. [How to get test ad Banners and test Interstitial ads working for adMob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862601/how-to-get-test-ad-banners-and-test-interstitial-ads-working-for-admob) did look promising, but there was no answer on how to add test devices.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can you add test devices to these and if so, how?

So here you go:

```
// request test interstitial ads
        AdRequest adRequestInterstitial = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice(testDeviceId)
            .build();

// request test banner ads
  AdRequest adRequestBanner = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice(testDeviceId)
            .build();
```

Comment: Didn't know that was possible ^^ fair enough hehe

Comment: error rises
The method addTestDevice(String) is undefined for the type AdRequest

Comment: @cyberpIrate then you have not integrated this adMob library properly.

Comment: If you don't integrate properly you can actually get banned from AdMob (One of my accounts did because I forgot to enable test ads.)

Answer (score 0):

A small hack & its done.....!
I have write few lines of code ,which will add every device as a test_device ,When you run your app in it .

Just Write this code before loading the add:

```
SharedPreferences var1 = context.getSharedPreferences("FBAdPrefs", 0);
        String i = u.b(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        if (!var1.getString("deviceIdHash", "").equals(i))
        {
            var1.edit().putString("deviceIdHash", i).apply();
        }

        AdSettings.addTestDevice(i);
```

It works for all type of facebook ad's ..!

Answer (score -1):

I use the admob test ads id:

1. For banner: **ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111**
2. For Interstitial : **ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712**

Refer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35432717/1233979)

Comment: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 ad_id test