# Is there is a problem in android 9 that stop banner ads

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

My banner ad and interstitial ads work well on devices under 8 and 9 but on 8 or 9 not work , but in my emulator work well on android 9

my app is published on google play my ad work well on devices under android 8 but android 8 or 9 not shown and work well on emulator with android 10 but on real device not work
in mainfest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="MyAppID" />
```

in gradle

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0'
```

in Activity

```
AdView adview2; 
adview2 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView2);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); adview2.loadAd(adRequest);
```

in xml

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="AdID"
        >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: which SDK are you using? Please post more details , preferably code to explain the issue you are facing.

Comment: my app is published on google play my ad work well on devices under android 8 but android 8 or 9 not shown and work well on emulator with android 10 but on real device not work

Comment: You can follow below link, i think it will helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955274/google-admob-android-working-on-only-one-device

Answer (score 0):

You have added only one test device for adRequest() in debug mode.

So it's working for that device only.

First of all, you don't need to test with a live account with real AdMob unit id,

you can use test ad unit id. And don't need to check if it is in debug mode or not.