# finding _id in Android illegal state exception row 0 col -1

Tags: android, database, android-intent, sqlite

I have tried to figure this out and googled through a fair few stack overflow responses but none of them seem to address this exact problem. I am trying to return the row ID so that I can update my database.

```
    String query= "SELECT * FROM climb_tbl WHERE climb_name ='"+climbname+"'";
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    long id = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    System.out.println(id);
```

As far as I can tell this should return the id value I need to then run the update statement, ive yet to write. Instead I get the error.....

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do you have `_id` column in your table?
2. Probably the cursor is empty. The `cur.moveToFirst()` returns `true` or `false`, so you can use it in the following way:

   ```
   if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
       long id = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
       System.out.println(id);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thankyou very much it was a problem with the cursor.

Comment: Suggestion: Log.i("YourClassName","Your message"); is better than System.out.printline(""). Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android