# retrieve server response code in string

Tags: java, android, response

I am trying to display the message based on the response from the server but somehow its failing everytime. When i am running the same code from java class seperately from different project by providing static values it is running properly and i am able to get the response code. Please refer the code and help me rectify the error.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, 
Runnable {
Context context;
EditText editTextNum, editText, editUserName, editPassword;
Button btnsend;
ProgressDialog pd;
String gateway_name;
Thread t;
Spinner spinner1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_userName);
    editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
    editTextNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_number);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerGateway);
    btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
    btnsend.setOnClickListener(this);
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage() {
    String usrname = editUserName.getText().toString();
    String usrPassword = editPassword.getText().toString();
    String number = editTextNum.getText().toString();
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    gateway_name = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
    String msgreciever = number;
    String testMessage = message;
    try {
        SmsSender.sendMessage(msgreciever, testMessage, usrname,
                usrPassword, gateway_name);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Sending Failed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        settingmenuClicked();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_inbox:
        showInbox();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isValid() {
    if (editUserName.getText().length() == 10
            && editPassword.getText().length() != 0
            && editTextNum.getText().length() == 10
            && editText.getText().length() != 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v == btnsend) {
        if (!isOnline()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "No Internet Access..Cannot Send SMS",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (!isValid()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "All fields are required. Try Again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Free Sms",
                    "Sending SMS..Please Wait..!!", true);
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

    }
}

public void settingmenuClicked() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Setting Menu Coming Soon",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void showHelp() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Help Coming Soon",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void showInbox() {
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, Inbox.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
}

public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sendMessage();
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

public Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        pd.dismiss();
        String response = SmsSender.responsecode;
        if(response == "1"){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sent Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(response == "-1"){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(response == "-2"){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(response == "-3"){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Message Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(response == "-4"){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(response == "-5"){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IP is blocked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unknown Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sent To Server",
            //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editTextNum.setText("");
        editText.setText("");
        editTextNum.requestFocus();
    }
};
}
```

**SmsSender.java**

```
public class SmsSender {

static final String _url = "http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx";
static final String charset = "UTF-8";
public static String responsecode = "0";

// to build the query string that will send the message
private static String buildRequestString(String targetPhoneNo,
        String message, String userName, String Password, String Gateway) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String[] params = new String[5];
    params[0] = userName;
    params[1] = Password;
    params[2] = message;
    params[3] = targetPhoneNo;
    params[4] = Gateway;

    String query = String.format(
            "uid=%s&pwd=%s&msg=%s&phone=%s&provider=%s",
            URLEncoder.encode(params[0], charset),
            URLEncoder.encode(params[1], charset),
            URLEncoder.encode(params[2], charset),
            URLEncoder.encode(params[3], charset),
            URLEncoder.encode(params[4], charset));
    return query;

}

public static void sendMessage(String reciever, String message, String userName, String password, String Gateway)
        throws Exception {
    // To establish the connection and perform the post request
    URLConnection connection = new URL(_url + "?"
            + buildRequestString(reciever, message, userName, password, Gateway)).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    // This automatically fires the request and we can use it to determine
    // the response status
    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    responsecode = br.readLine();

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // To DO
    //String testPhoneNo = "9876543210";
    //String testMessage = "Sending Messages From java is not too hard";
    //sendMessage(testPhoneNo, testMessage);
}

 }
```

Comment: What is the error? Does it throw an exception or just not work? If it doesn't work, what does it do instead? If it's an exception where is it thrown?

Comment: @Fr33dan its not showing showing any error. just not returning any response code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a victim of too much copy and paste from [the example](http://ubaid.tk/api-usage/). I suspect you are getting a response (otherwise you would encounter an exception). You are then are just [throwing it away to a System.out.println()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android). Then when you go to set `responsecode` [readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) returns null.

I tried to test it for myself, but I cannot use the API outside of India.