# Java Activity TextEdit input not printing when I click the appropriate button

Tags: java, android, input, printing, textedit

Here is my activity's code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String height, weight;
    String dob, dov;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enterClicked();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void enterClicked()
{
    height = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
    weight = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString();
    System.out.println( height + " " + weight );
}
}
```

When I run this code on the emulator I want it to take in the text I input and when I click the button I want it to retrieve the text and print it in the log. It doesn't currently print. I don't have any pre-compile errors and it appears my links to my EditTexts are successful. What might be the issue?

Comment: Where are you expecting the output from `System.out.println( height + " " + weight );` to be?

Comment: I wouldn't ever completely rely on logs. Use `Toast` or even better set breakpoints and see what your variables contain at different points to get an idea what's going on

Answer (score 0):

you can't use System.out.println for android apps.  See this question: [Why doesn't "System.out.println" work in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android)

Comment: Bruce is trying to print to `System.out`. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Log` for this purpose. It provides logging options for a number of scenarios. You can direct and segregate log messages based on their nature. Example:

~ Debug:

```
Log.d(String tag, String msg)
```

~ Info
    Log.i(String tag, String msg)

....
....

In your case, you can use Log.i as such:

```
Log.i("MainActivity", height + " " + weight);
```

The output will be available in `logcat` under the `info` view.

You can read up on the options that `Log` class provides here: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Log` or `Toast`. These are the best ways:

1. `Log.i("Display TextView check", height + " " + weight);`
2. `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text check:" + height + " " + weight, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`