# Using an if statment onto an EditText

Tags: android, if-statement, equals

I have an alert box with an EditText.
It doesn't go through the "if" when I try to compare it to the user input.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Number of players: ");


     final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
        }
    });

    alert.show();
```

it doesn't work from here on:

```
String newString = input.getText().toString();

if(newString.equals("2"))

    {
        System.out.print("lol");

    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When are you executing the code in your second listing?

Comment: it is also on onCreate

Comment: Wrap code in method  which you want to execute on Ok Alert Button click then call method inside onClick method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the code of your second listing in the `OnClickListener` of one of your buttons (I guess you want it to be executed after the Ok button is pressed):

```
...
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        String newString = input.getText().toString();
        if(newString.equals("2")) {
            System.out.print("lol");
        }
    }
});
...
```

You cannot expect to get the user input immediately after the dialog is shown. The user simply does not have time to type anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the `if` is working correctly, you just don't see it. Using `System.out.print();` in an android application is not advisable since there is no console to output to. Use **Logcat** instead.

[More info on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android)