# System.out To Android Logcat In Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, system.out

I am working on an Android project with some classes that I plan to pull out as a pure Java.jar (to be used in other java related projects). In these pure Java classes, I use `System.out` to log. This is also an Android application though, so n my Android classes, I obviously use `Log`.

In monitoring the pure java classes, I can't get `System.out` to print out in my Eclipse logcat. I do see `System.err` though.

Does anyone know how to get `System.out` to display in LogCat in this fabled `Log.i` level?

**Setup**

1. Nexus 7 - Android 4.4.4 - Stock
2. Eclipse Kepler
3. Android SDK 21
4. Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit
5. Monitoring all messages tab in Logcat, logcat set to verbose

**I've Tried**

```
adb root
adb shell start
adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
adb shell stop
```

- Logcat is set to verbose
- Nothing in Console under Android or DDMS

Comment: Write a log wrapper, or use an existing one.

Comment: @DaveNewton `System.out` is printed in logcat right? :)

Comment: What do you mean a log wrapper? When you say log do you mean the Android class `Log` or do you mean the general verb log? What am I wrapping? `System.out` ? Aren't we stuck in the same situation then?

Comment: An log wrapper would be unnecessary, you can better solve the problem you have -edit: Because normally `System.out` is printed to logcat

Comment: @WHDeveloper Yeah that's the same impression I have from what I've read. I think it's a setting somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: Do you have an custom ROM OP?

Comment: @WHDeveloper No, updated the setup to refer to that, that's a good tidbit to know.

Comment: What I have found: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2220559/1470496)

Comment: Yeah I read that, and a few other stack overflows.

Comment: Than the comment was unnecessary, because AOSP android would probably not do that (at least, that is what I am thinking)

Comment: Good thing to update the post with the things you already tried, it helps us to post more relevant information and not the things you already tried!

Comment: What filter does your logcat have?

Comment: Using the All messages tab

Answer (score 0):

Now you can send your Pure Java project logs into warning level for example...

```
    OutputStream os = new OutputStream() {

        @Override
        public synchronized void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int len) {
            Log.w("blah", new String(buffer));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int oneByte)
                throws IOException {
            // Not really sure what to do here...
        }
    };
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(os));
    System.out.println("Adam.");
```

Comment: Except that now my pure java classes are linking to Android classes, specifically `Log`

Comment: He wants to have a jar with classes that can be used in both Android and normal java projects, importing log will only work on Android and not in the normal java projects

Comment: True, but he can do this from the android project and it would apply to all the code running in the jvm... isn't that what he wants?

Comment: I expect to pull out some of these classes into a purely Java based project that will be jarred as a library for use in future java projects not running on an Android JVM

Comment: You need to write this code in your Android project, preferable in your CustomApplication.onCreate() or as a static block in your first activity. This has nothing to do with your code or how you break it into project, and will not have any effect on another pure Java project.