# onResponse(String response) response value not printed in logcat

Tags: android, android-volley

The condition response.equalsIgnoreCase("success") becomes always false, thought log.d print response = "success".  Also how come printed response from system.out.print line is always empty. The goal is to receive the response from the request and satisfy the condition.

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        Constant.SUBSCRIPTION_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        System.out.println("xxSuccess "+response);

        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

            SimpleDialogFragment
            .createBuilder(
                    getActivity(),
                    getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager())
                    .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                    .setMessage(R.string.subscription_sucess)
                    .show();

        } else {

            SimpleDialogFragment
            .createBuilder(
                    getActivity(),
                    getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager())
                    .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                    .setMessage(R.string.subscription_failure)
                    .show();
        }


    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        // error
        Util.volleyError(error);
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        params.put("name", firstName + " " + name);
        params.put("email", contact_email);
        params.put("profession", profession);
        params.put("dob", dateofbirth);
        params.put("gender", gender);
        params.put("region", region);
        params.put("country", country);

        return params;

    }


};

queue.add(postRequest);
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android

Comment: get your point but response.equalsIgnoreCase("success") becomes always false, thought log.d print response = "success"

Comment: Your comment has nothing do to what you questioned. Please update your question with your problem.

Comment: Don't use `System.out.println`. Use `Log` only. If you use Log what is the result?

Comment: result is either success or failure with log.d, However i want to get the string from response but it is always null. Thought i do String my_response = response.toString(); it is not assigned

Comment: If `response` is always null then you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: the webservice is receiving the values successfully and Log.d prints failure/success i do not think it is a webservice problem but volley library is it possible

Comment: I don't even see any Log.d in this code.

Comment: i remove it when revert back Log.d("TAG",response);

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to explain.

Comment: i am retrieving the "response" value which is a string that is either success or failure based on webservice response but i am not getting the value

Comment: first check whether the service return any response or not...u can use Advance REST client app for chrome...and then check in android...

Comment: you are contradicting "the condition response.equalsIgnoreCase("success") becomes always false, thought log.d print response = "success". Also how come printed response from system.out.print line is always empty." ... how this is possible?