# Why Android doc uses System.out

Tags: android

I copied a sample from [MotionEvent javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html). It did not print anything to logcat so i looked more deeply and realized that it uses `System.out` instead of `Log`. Is it a bug in Javadoc or did I miss something and is it supposed to print somewhere I can see?

```
void printSamples(MotionEvent ev) {
 final int historySize = ev.getHistorySize();
 final int pointerCount = ev.getPointerCount();
 for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {
     System.out.printf("At time %d:", ev.getHistoricalEventTime(h));
     for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
         System.out.printf("  pointer %d: (%f,%f)",
             ev.getPointerId(p), ev.getHistoricalX(p, h), ev.getHistoricalY(p, h));
     }
 }
```

Comment: On most devices `System.out` gets output to logcat with log level `info`. Make sure you don't have that level filtered out.

Comment: IDE is connected to Nexus 4 with Android 5.1. I cannot see it there. Log.d messages are present.

Comment: @LeosLiterak `Log.d` is _debug_. I think `info` is one level below. Edit: I was wrong `info` has higher priority than `debug` and should be shown.

Comment: @Gumbo I wrote it because if debug is displayed than info must be displayed as well.

Comment: @laalto so the answer is that they used system.out because it is supposed to work in most cases (except my phone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` and provides handy helpers such as `printf()` that `Log` does not. Also on many configurations, `System.out` [is redirected to `Log` with log level `INFO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android). This is just guessing but probably these are some of the reasons why the original snippet uses `System.out`.

You are free to replace the `System.out.printf(...)` calls with `android.util.Log.i("sometag", String.format(...))` to get similar output in logcat.

Comment: Would be nice having Log.df, ef and other shortcuts for formatted printing.