# Getting IOException with no error message Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpurlconnection, openweathermap

Using Android Studio 2.0

Getting no output for

```
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Response Code" + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Error Stream" + urlConnection.getErrorStream());
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Request Method" + urlConnection.getRequestMethod());
```

using **Built URI** on browser gives me correct result.

before  `urlConnection.connect();` calling getRequestMethod() gives me method name GET .

**Code**

```
try {
    // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
    // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
    // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
    final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
    final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
    final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
    final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
    final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
    final String APPID_PARAM = "APPID";

    Uri builtUri = Uri
            .parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL)
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
            .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
            .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
            .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
            .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM,
                    BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY).build();

    URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

    // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    // urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.connect();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Response Code" + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Error Stream" + urlConnection.getErrorStream());
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Request Method" + urlConnection.getRequestMethod());

    // Read the input stream into a String
    // InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    InputStream inputStream;
    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
        inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
    } else {
        inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    }
    // Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Response Code" +urlConnection.getHeaderFields());

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    if (inputStream == null) {
        // Nothing to do.
        return null;
    }
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't
        // affect parsing)
        // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out
        // the completed
        // buffer for debugging.
        buffer.append(line + "\n");
    }

    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
        // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.

        return null;
    }
    forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "JSON Response " + forecastJsonStr);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
    // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no
    // point in attemping
    // to parse it.
    return null;
} finally {
    if (urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Error Log

> 04-22 18:42:16.444 9011-9011/com.android.serverwarrior.sunshine
> E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
>
> 04-22 18:42:17.405
> 9011-9314/com.android.serverwarrior.sunshine E/FetchWeatherTask: Error

Comment: aren't you swallowing  the exception with this line? Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);

Comment: error message is always in the logcat if you have set your filters correct. There must be more...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I am not using any filter on logcat .

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra I have posted that, what I am getting on logcat.

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra if you want me to use something else there, please let me know.

Comment: Can you print the full stack trace with a System.out.print instead?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android

Comment: mmm I see. then in the catch add this `String s = Log.getStackTraceString (e);`  `Log.e(LOG_TAG,s);`

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I am getting a new error with my existing error, which is related to device, is this the cause for IOException ?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra check the edit, error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea but, I connect the phone to a wifi network, and send the request again and I got the JSON resposne .

I confirmed it, with out the network connection, I a not getting the output.

About

> 04-22 18:42:16.444 9011-9011/com.android.serverwarrior.sunshine
>   E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

This is because the Samsung device, what I got from other posts on this error.so this part can be ignored.

Comment: yep...samsung device....I also have some problems with samsung galaxy s3....it has his own life and tries to annoy you.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs It is very bad to know, that the problems are not new but still unsolved .

Comment: @Opiatefuchs try running Android Studio as Admin, it is really faster than usual, this is something I noticed during this, as I spent nearly 6 hrs on it.