# onItemSelectedListener doesn't get triggered

Tags: java, android, onitemselectedlistener

I am calling `onItemSelectedListener` in my spinner but the code inside `onItemSelected` is not being executed.

Here is my code:

```
final MaterialBetterSpinner materialDesignSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner)
                findViewById(R.id.states_list);

ArrayAdapter<String> stateArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.oman_states));

materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(stateArrayAdapter);


materialDesignSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                System.out.println("works");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

`System.out.println()` is not executed

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: May be your MaterialBetterSpinner is catching OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: I had run your code and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Behrouz I think that your MaterialBetterSpinner custom class extends OnItemClickListener and so the clicking events captured there. So it wont get called on your setOnItemSelectedListener. So check that custom class.

Comment: @Rameshbabu oh okay, thanks will check it now

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`android.util.Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) instead of `System.out`, which doesn't always work. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android).