# Add new contacts (36 items)

Tags: android, addition, contacts, multiple-insert

im trying to add new contacts to the phone but he does only the first 12 items.
i want to try all current 36 items and maybe more add to the phone contacts.

```
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("[[DEBUG]] [DW-UPDATE] LINE: " + line);
                String[] split = line.split(";", -1);

                split[2] = split[2].replace("/", "").replace("-", "");

                if (!contactExists(mActivity, split[2])) {
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED)
                    .build());
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Integer.valueOf(split[0]))
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, split[1])
                    .build());
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Integer.valueOf(split[0]))
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, split[2])
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .build());

                    try {
                        mActivity.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

function contactExists:

```
public boolean contactExists(Activity _activity, String number) {
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cur = _activity.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (cur != null)
            cur.close();
    }
    return false;
}// contactExists
```

what i must do, to work this better?

Comment: Just to confirm, how many times are you seeing `[[DEBUG]] [DW-UPDATE] LINE:` appear? I'd also recommend using [`Log.d()`](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html) instead to print log messages to Android's Logcat.

Comment: all 36 items print the message. What is the different between Log.d and System.out ?

Comment: `System.out`, traditionally for logging to the Java console, gets redirected to `Log.i()` in more recent versions of Android, but previously it didn't get picked up by Android's logging tool `Logcat`. Using `Log` ensures that logging messages are passed to logcat. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220559/469080

Comment: Using `Log` also allows for [different logging levels](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html#level) based on the severity of what you're logging (e.g. debug message, warning, error)

Comment: I have a feeling you're using the wrong back reference. Just after your `if` statement, add `int backref = ops.size();`, and use `backref` instead of `split[0]`. Not confident enough to call it an answer, but give it a go.

Comment: oh thanks you. that was my mistake. it works perfect!

Comment: Cheers, full answer added. Please upvote and accept if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your back references when adding the additional contact data. The back reference should refer to the position of your `RawContacts.CONTENT_URI` insert within your list of operations (`ops`), not the position of the contact within your raw data file. You can fix this by keeping track of the size of `ops` through each iteration:

```
if (!contactExists(mActivity, split[2])) {
    int backRef = ops.size();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(...)
        .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRef)
        .withValue(...)
        .build()

    .build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRef)
        .withValue(...)
    .build());

    try {
        mActivity.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```