# RecyclerView itemView.setOnClick Listener Not Working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, click

I have a recycler view and I want to return the position in the list that was clicked. I have tried to set an OnClickListener on the itemView, but this doesn't seem to get triggered upon it being clicked

I have tried to set the OnClickListener inside the ViewHolder method but this did not work either

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.evacName.setText(evacNames.get(position).toString());
    holder.editTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    holder.deleteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("CLICKED ROW " + position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return evacNames.size();
}

class HomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView evacName;
    TextView editTextView;
    TextView deleteTextView;

    public HomeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        evacName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.evacProcedureTextView);
        editTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextView);
        deleteTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteTextView);

        swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipeLayout);

        swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.LayDown);

        swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper));

        swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
                //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {
                //you are swiping.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
                //when the BottomView totally show.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {
                //when user's hand released.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Upon clicking the row I am expecting to see the position of the row clicked via System.out

Comment: There's multiple click listeners registered in the view holder. It's possible the click is getting consumed by one of the other listeners. Put some other logging statements or System.out lines in those other click listeners to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Just remove style in your xml and then try your method. Your method is right so it's working after remove style in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) and see output in Android Studio LogCat:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.v("Your Filter", "CLICKED ROW " + position);
        }
    });
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android) for more information about `Log` and `System.out` in Android

Answer (score 0):

i have read your question and i have implement in my project. i have find a problem and its solution. in recyclerview onclick listener is work on only on item means that you try onclick listener on itemveiw as well as view click its not work because its both are similar. in this situation onclick  work only for first view(editTextView) , if you print postion in edittextview onclicklistener its print because its implement on first .

please see this code and screenshot.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Myholder myholder, final int i) {

    myholder.text.setText(name[i]);



     myholder.text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("check click: "+i);
            Log.e(TAG+"check_clcik_view:",""+i);

        }
    });
    myholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("check item view click:"+i);
            Log.e(TAG+"check_clcik_item:",""+i);
        }
    });

}
```

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code it should work.

```
  class HomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{  // implementing  View.OnClickListener will handle all click event's inside the holder and will keep your code also clean

      TextView evacName;
      TextView editTextView;
      TextView deleteTextView;

      public HomeViewHolder(View itemView) {
          super(itemView);

          evacName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.evacProcedureTextView);
          editTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextView);
          deleteTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteTextView);

          swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipeLayout);

          swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.LayDown);

          swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper));

          swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
                  //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.
              }

              @Override
              public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {
                  //you are swiping.
              }

              @Override
              public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
                  //when the BottomView totally show.
              }

              @Override
              public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {
                  //when user's hand released.
              }
          });
      }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
       //you can handle any type of even specifically for `deleteTextView` or itemView`
       Log.v("Your Filter", "CLICKED ROW " + getAdapterPosition());
    }
  }
```

**Note:** According to your requirement you want to add listener to the holder not the the `deleteTextView` or `itemView` .Setting two ClickListener are actually overComplicating your logic which can be easily handled inside `HomeViewHolder`

```
holder.deleteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {   
     Log.v("Your Filter", "CLICKED ROW " + getAdapterPosition());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can intialize whatever your layout parent and use onclick method , i`ll give you an example.:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/mMessagelayout">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_style"
    android:backgroundTint="#f3e5f5"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        tools:text="Message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:text="Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

That was my xml layout for each item in recyclerview and
there is my Adapter Code:

```
public static class SentMessages extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView text,name;
    LinearLayout mParent;
    public SentMessages(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        mParent= (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mMessagelayout);
    }



 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage=messages.get(position);
    switch (friendlyMessage.getType()){
        case FriendlyMessage.CHAT_TYPE_SENT:
            ((SentMessages)holder).name.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
            ((SentMessages)holder).text.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
            ((SentMessages)holder).mParent.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(context,"Message :"+friendlyMessage.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

Ihope you get it.