# Logcat is not Printing

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I am trying to Print some messages using `Log.i`  but it doesn't print anything, the problem starts after I updated the Android studio.

How can I solve the problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("check","**************checking");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Comment: Add some screenshoot or something so we can see verything which device are you using, etc...

Comment: Check to see whether it prints when using `logcat` via a terminal session, `adb logcat -v color check:I *:S`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate solution, but it's not the best.

```
System.out.print();
```

Comment: Using this will make it difficult to search, as it does not have tag.

Comment: @dcanh121 I was just providing an alternative. Searching was not something the question stated was a necessity.. Why the downvote?

Comment: You can always just incorporate the tag into your message

Comment: Using "Log" class has many advantages, rather than using System.out.println(). 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220559

Comment: @dcanh121 Sure it does, but again, I was just providing an alternative suggestion. Why downvote an alternative suggestion that works (for better or for worse).. To deter new contributors to the site from trying to help?

Comment: @Dylan I appreciate the alternate solution even if it's not the best. Cannot remove downvote unless the answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select the device you are using, you can do it on the top left side of the Logcat.

for example if you used an emulator and than a device make sure the device is selected.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the tag constant

```
public static final string TAG = "MainActivity"
```

Then do

```
Log.d(TAG, YOURMESSAGE)
```

Also as an alternative you can use System.out